# Calling python functions correctly and running a scraped list of names through Selenium browser search bar

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have the following code, and I can't seem to find an answer on SO (if there's a question out there that I haven't combed through, please close this specific Q):

```
def f0_member_list_links():


    member_list = [
                "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives"]

    return member_list
```

```
def f1_house_list(member_list):

    # this was super to easy to get the actual data... but failing on actual efficient execution
    house_get = pd.read_html(member_list[0], header = 0)[6]
    house_init = house_get['Member']
    house_full = pd.DataFrame(house_init.str.split(' ', 2).to_list())
    house_first = house_full[0]
    house_last = house_full[1]
    house_last = pd.DataFrame(house_last)
    house_last = house_last.iloc[0:434]
    house_last.columns = ['Member']

    return house_last
```

The above prints a list of all House members (I think the code is overwritten - as in the `pd.`are overused, yes?) -

```
def f3_disclosure_links():

    disclosure_links = ["http://clerk.house.gov/public_disc/financial-search.aspx"]

    return disclosure_links


def f4_house_disc(x, y):

    house_last_dic = x, y

    for i in (house_last_dic): 

        url = disclosure_links[0]
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =r"/Users/dir/Documents/chromedriver")
        driver.get(url)
        house_search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_cphMain_txbLast_nm"]')
        house_search.clear()
        house_search.send_keys(i)
        search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_cphMain_btnSearch"]')
        search_button.click()
        driver.close()

    return figure_out_later
```

And here's how the functions are called:

```
member_urls = f0_member_list_links()
house_lists = f1_house_list(member_urls)
house_disc = f4_house_disc(house_lists, disc_links)
```

**TLDR**: How do I get the functions to iterate through the list of names in the search bar of the provided website?

Answer (score 0):

So, you first get a list of names from wikipedia. Then, for every name in your list of names, you want to perform a search on the `.gov` page?

I think pandas or Selenium is overkill for this. All you need is requests and BeautifulSoup. By logging my network traffic, I saw that this page makes a POST request. As long as you can provide the same payload, you can imitate such a request. The response is an `.aspx` page with all the data baked in unfortunately, but that's the nature of `.aspx`, so you'll still have to parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup.

In addition, for some reason, the names in the table rows have a bunch of whitespace in the middle. There's also some leading and trailing whitespace, which you could remove with `str.strip`, but since there's whitespace in the middle as well, it's probably easier to just make a regex, which I did:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "http://clerk.house.gov/public_disc/financial-search.aspx"

data = {
    "ctl00_cphMain_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField": ";;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:1547e793-5b7e-48fe-8490-03a375b13a33:de1feab2:f9cec9bc:a0b0f951:a67c2700",
    "ctl00_cphMain_tabCont_ClientState": "{\"ActiveTabIndex\":0,\"TabState\":[true,true]}",
    "__EVENTTARGET": "",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
    "__VIEWSTATE": "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",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "43F3FF2D",
    "__SCROLLPOSITIONX": "3",
    "__SCROLLPOSITIONY": "0",
    "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": "",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": "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",
    "ctl00$txbSearchBox": "",
    "ctl00$cphMain$txbLast_nm": "clark",
    "ctl00$cphMain$txbFiling_year": "",
    "ctl00$cphMain$ddlState": "",
    "ctl00$cphMain$txbDistrict_cd": "",
    "ctl00$cphMain$btnSearch": "Search"
}

response = requests.post(url, data=data)
response.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

name_pattern = "([^\\s]+)\\s+([^\\s]+)"

for row in soup.select("td[class=\"alt_row\"]"):
    match = re.search(name_pattern, row.text)
    if match is None:
        continue
    print(" ".join(match.groups()))
```

Output:

```
CLARKE, HON.HANSEN
CLARKE, HON.HANSEN
CLARKE, HON.HANSEN
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
CLARKE, HON.YVETTE
Clarke, Ms.Yvette
Clarke, Ms.Yvette
Clarke, Ms.Yvette
Clarke, Hon.Yvette
Clarke, Hon.Yvette
Clarke, Hon.Yvette
>>>
```

It looks like the table often has multiple entries for the same person, hence the repeating names in the output. These entries contain financial disclosure statements for different years for the same person. If you're not interested in these distinct documents for each person, you can look for `tr` tags with `"class": "alt_row"` instead.

This still doesn't implement the feature I think you're going for, though, which is to iterate over a list of names, and perform a new search for each name. Using this example, though, it should be pretty straightforward - you just have a list of names and make a for-loop, and then make a new post-request for each iteration. The only thing that would change between iterations in the POST payload (the `data` dictionary) is the `ctl00$cphMain$txbLast_nm` field (notice how I just hardcoded `"clark"` in there).

Comment: Yeah, that's about the gist of it. Scrape each name, and then port that into the search bar of the website. I'll worry about search results later - just want to have something working that's 1) functionalized and 2) a simple scraper. Thanks! Will hack away from your example